# Adding an alert to Javascript verification

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript and PHP code on my website (which is being used for the login system):

```
<form id='login' style="position: absolute; top: 10px; right: 100px;" action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<input type='text' name='username' class="formlogin" placeholder='Username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="20" />
<span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
<input type='password' class="formlogin" placeholder="Password" name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
<span id='login_password_errorloc' class='error'></span>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
<div class='short_explanation'><a href='reset-pwd-req.php'>Forgot Password?</a></div>
</form>
<script>
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("login");
frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
frmvalidator.addValidation("username","req","Please provide your username");
frmvalidator.addValidation("password","req","Please provide the password");
// ]]>
</script>
</ul>
</div>
```

Currently, if a user doesn't type in their password, text appears saying 'please provide the password'. How do I edit that to make the password field turn from white to red?

Comment: How is anyone supposed to answer this? We don't even know what JS library you are using for validation!

Comment: I'm simple asking how to make the text 'please provide your password' appear in an alert - I don't get how that's hard to understand.

Comment: Because we have no clue how your `Validator` class is using the message... all you do is pass it to a library that does something with it. (by the way, `alert` is incredibly annoying for form validation - showing a message nicely next to the erroneous field is much better)

Comment: I'll re-word this question using your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure css ([example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Iow0KiadbbyxOFaj4hLQ?p=preview))

```
<style>
    input:invalid {
        border: 1px solid green;
    }
    :required { 
        background-color: yellow;
    }
<style>

<input type="email" required>
```